# Select rows grouped by a column having max aggregate

Tags: mysql, group-by, having

Given the following data set, how would I find the email addresses that were references for the most `ApplicationID`s that have an "Accepted" decision?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `EmailReferences` (
  `ApplicationID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ApplicationID`, `Email`)
);
INSERT INTO EmailReferences (ApplicationID, Email)
VALUES
(1, 'ref10@test.org'), (1, 'ref11@test.org'), (1, 'ref12@test.org'),
(2, 'ref20@test.org'), (2, 'ref21@test.org'), (2, 'ref22@test.org'),
(3, 'ref11@test.org'), (3, 'ref31@test.org'), (3, 'ref32@test.org'),
(4, 'ref40@test.org'), (4, 'ref41@test.org'), (4, 'ref42@test.org'),
(5, 'ref50@test.org'), (5, 'ref51@test.org'), (5, 'ref52@test.org'),
(6, 'ref60@test.org'), (6, 'ref11@test.org'), (6, 'ref62@test.org'),
(7, 'ref70@test.org'), (7, 'ref71@test.org'), (7, 'ref72@test.org'),
(8, 'ref10@test.org'), (8, 'ref81@test.org'), (8, 'ref82@test.org')
;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `FinalDecision` (
  `ApplicationID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Decision` ENUM('Accepted', 'Denied') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ApplicationID`)
);
INSERT INTO FinalDecision (ApplicationID, Decision)
VALUES
(1, 'Accepted'), (2, 'Denied'),
(3, 'Accepted'), (4, 'Denied'),
(5, 'Denied'),   (6, 'Denied'),
(7, 'Denied'),   (8, 'Accepted')
;
```

Fiddle of same:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03bcf2/1

Initially, I was using `LIMIT 1` and `ORDER BY CountDecision DESC`, like so:

```
SELECT  er.email, COUNT(fd.Decision) AS CountDecision
FROM    EmailReferences AS er
JOIN    FinalDecision AS fd ON er.ApplicationID = fd.ApplicationID
WHERE   fd.Decision = 'Accepted'
GROUP   BY er.email
ORDER   BY CountDecision DESC
LIMIT   1
;
```

However, it occurred to me that I could have multiple email addresses that referred different "most accepted" decisions (i.e., a tie, so to speak), and those would be filtered out (is that the right phrasing?) with the `LIMIT` keyword.

I then tried a variation on the above query, replacing the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` lines with:

```
HAVING MAX(CountDecision)
```

But I realized that that's only half a statement: `MAX(CountDecision)` needs to be compared to something. I just don't know what.

Any pointers would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Note: this is for a homework assignment.

**Update:** To be clear, I'm trying to find value and count of `Email`s from `EmailReferences`. However, I only want rows that have `FinalDecision.Decision = 'Accepted'` (on matching `ApplicantID`s). Based on my data, the result *should* be:

```
Email          | CountDecision
---------------+--------------
ref10@test.org | 2
ref11@test.org | 2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Comment: @Ben That question looks like it only replies on data from one table. I'm trying to group data from one table (`EmailReferences`) but using matching a data that meets a criteria from another table (`FinalDecision`), joined on the `ApplicantID` columns. See my update. :)

Comment: Can you edit the question to contain only the correct, relevant information?

Comment: @Strawberry Done. Sorry, and thanks.

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry - I guess I misunderstood what you were asking. Thanks for the edit. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example...

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.email
            , COUNT(*) total
         FROM emailreferences x
         JOIN finaldecision y
           ON y.applicationid = x.applicationid
        WHERE y.decision = 'accepted'
        GROUP
           BY x.email
     ) a
  JOIN
     ( SELECT COUNT(*) total
         FROM emailreferences x
         JOIN finaldecision y
           ON y.applicationid = x.applicationid
        WHERE y.decision = 'accepted'
        GROUP
           BY x.email
        ORDER 
           BY total DESC 
        LIMIT 1
     ) b
    ON b.total = a.total;
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL still lack window functions, but when version 8 is production ready, this becomes easier. So for fuure reference, or for those databases like Mariadb that already have window functions:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `EmailReferences` (
>   `ApplicationID` INT NOT NULL,
>   `Email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`ApplicationID`, `Email`)
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO EmailReferences (ApplicationID, Email)
> VALUES
> (1, 'ref10@test.org'), (1, 'ref11@test.org'), (1, 'ref12@test.org'),
> (2, 'ref20@test.org'), (2, 'ref21@test.org'), (2, 'ref22@test.org'),
> (3, 'ref30@test.org'), (3, 'ref31@test.org'), (3, 'ref32@test.org'),
> (4, 'ref40@test.org'), (4, 'ref41@test.org'), (4, 'ref42@test.org'),
> (5, 'ref50@test.org'), (5, 'ref51@test.org'), (5, 'ref52@test.org'),
> (6, 'ref60@test.org'), (6, 'ref11@test.org'), (6, 'ref62@test.org'),
> (7, 'ref70@test.org'), (7, 'ref71@test.org'), (7, 'ref72@test.org'),
> (8, 'ref10@test.org'), (8, 'ref81@test.org'), (8, 'ref82@test.org')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `FinalDecision` (
>   `ApplicationID` INT NOT NULL,
>   `Decision` ENUM('Accepted', 'Denied') NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`ApplicationID`)
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO FinalDecision (ApplicationID, Decision)
> VALUES
> (1, 'Accepted'), (2, 'Denied'),
> (3, 'Accepted'), (4, 'Denied'),
> (5, 'Denied'),   (6, 'Denied'),
> (7, 'Denied'),   (8, 'Accepted')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> select email, CountDecision
> from (
>      SELECT   er.email, COUNT(fd.Decision) AS CountDecision
>             , max(COUNT(fd.Decision)) over() maxCountDecision
>      FROM EmailReferences AS er
>      JOIN FinalDecision AS fd ON er.ApplicationID = fd.ApplicationID
>      WHERE    fd.Decision = 'Accepted'
>      GROUP    BY er.email
>      ) d
> where CountDecision = maxCountDecision
> ```
>
> ```
> email          | CountDecision
> :------------- | ------------:
> ref10@test.org |             2
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=82d2358dc8faff00a28cc079a059b27b)*